# No module named pytrustnfe.nfe (Odoo Server Error)

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I have some problems to install Odoo Module named **ODOO BRASIL - MODULO BASE (br_base)**.

The error message is:

> O módulo "br_base" não pode ser instalado porque uma dependência
>   externa não foi encontrada: No module named pytrustnfe.nfe

Translating:

> The module "br_base not be installed because external dependency not
>   founded: No module named pytrustnfe.nfe

Comment: this github post should help: https://github.com/Trust-Code/odoo-brasil/issues/100

Comment: How did you install odoo. And what platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux:

```
pip install PyTrustNFe
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependency of **PyTrustNFe** called **xmlsec** didn't installed. When I try install this dependency I had this.

```
[root@agileweb ~]# pip install xmlsec
Collecting xmlsec
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/42/d7cd323c91d4706f3cc32ffe7d5f851ab8ef9898ccb350f6ba593dd8b89a/xmlsec-1.3.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pkgconfig in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from xmlsec) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.0 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from xmlsec) (3.7.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: xmlsec
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for xmlsec ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-sk_Ibz/xmlsec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-Vx1fna --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find xmlsec1 config. Are libxmlsec1-dev and pkg-config installed?
  *********************************************************************************

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for xmlsec
  Running setup.py clean for xmlsec
Failed to build xmlsec
Installing collected packages: xmlsec
  Running setup.py install for xmlsec ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-sk_Ibz/xmlsec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-qiBfpy/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find xmlsec1 config. Are libxmlsec1-dev and pkg-config installed?
    *********************************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-sk_Ibz/xmlsec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-qiBfpy/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-sk_Ibz/xmlsec/
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to solve this problem would be PIP3 since this dependency is getting deprecated in python2.7

```
pip3 install PyTrustNFe3==1.0.35
```